# Creating normal distribution in python

Tags: python, iteration, normal-distribution

I try to create a normal distribution in python. I made the following code:

```
    prior = []
    variance = 20
    mean = 0.5
    x = -100

    while x <= 100:
            normal_distribution = 1/np.sqrt(1*np.pi*variance*variance)*np.exp(np.power(x-mean,2)/(2*variance*variance))
            prior.extend(normal_distribution)
            ++x
```

But I got a type error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

I tried that the normal_distribution = ... Has a value outside the while loop.
I don't exactly understand why it can't iterate.

Comment: don't utter the object. Always a bad idea... Next thing you know, you'll be muttering....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. You are looking for `.append`, not `.extend`; this is the source of the error, as `.extend` requires **iterable** object as an argument, so it can append **each of its elements** to the list. You are adding a single element - this is what `.append` is for
2. Your equation for pdf is invalid, you should have

   - `2` instead of `1` under the square root
   - negation inside `exp`
   - your `variance` variable is used in the meaning of `std`

   `1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*variance)*np.exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*variance))`
3. There is no such thing as `++x` in python, use `x += 1`

Comment: ' 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*variance**2)*np.exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*variance)) ' Inside the square is a variance**2 I think! Thank you!

Comment: no Daniel, this is far from being correct; check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution ; variance = sigma^2

Comment: Right! I see now! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: It looks like the goal is to calculate the distribution, not to draw from it. `np.random.normal` doesn't look like the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

As far as I see, `normal_distribution` is scalar-valued, thus it'd be `prior.append(normal_distribution)`, not `prior.extend(normal_distribution)`  .

Btw - appending in a loop is not performance-friendly, let alone idiomatic.

Better use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) like

prior = [(f(x) for x in range(-100, 101)]

where `f` is the function or [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) you use to generate your data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to `extend`. If you go and look at the doc for `extend` you'll find

```
class list(object)  
def extend(self, t) Inferred type: (self: list[T], t: Iterable[T]) -> None   L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements from the utterable
```

so you can now see why your code fails. It is indeed trying to iterate the object that you pass to `extend`, and, as you rightly point out, it can't. so, boom!

What you want is `append`

```
class list(object)  

def append(self, x) Inferred type: (self: list[T], x: T) -> None   L.append(object) -- append object to end
```

Changing this will lead you to the next exciting part of the debugging process, determining why your loop is infinite :) Good luck